# How to deploy web api project in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, deployment, mono, owin

I want to deploy my web api project to ubuntu, this is not .net core project. After searching a long time, I found all of the articles are talking about how to deploy asp.net core project in linux. Anybody can help how to deploy a standard .net framework web api project to linux? Mono or Owin can help? any resources I can refer?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what is your web api project what technology component does it use?

Comment: asp.net web api, .net4.5

Comment: It is not a supported approach by Microsoft, so you will be fully on your own. If you intend to use a server like Jexus, https://jexus.codeplex.com/documentation then the steps are clear. If you want to use Apache/nginx, then you still need to find the relevant materials via Google.